# C# ボタンコントロールにドラッグドロップをさせたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

フォーム上に貼り付けたボタンに、テキストファイルをドラッグドロップしてきて、
指定してあるテキストエディタをProcess.Startで立ち上げてファイルを開こうとしています。

ボタンを押すと、テキストエディタが開くということはできますが、それでは
エクスプローラーから編集したいファイルを開くということが一度にできません。

そのため、ボタンを単純にクリックすれば、引数なしで外部プログラムを起動させ、
ドラッグドロップならば引数付きで起動するようにしたいと思ったのですが…。

ボタン自体はドラッグドロップは受け付けないのでしょうか。
AllowDropをTrueにしただけでテストしても、ドラッグ時に×のマウスカーソルの
ままです。

実装そのものができないのでしょうか。
それとも、他に何か原因がありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowDrop`を設定しても、ドラッグイベントを処理しなければドロップすることはできません。以下を参考に実装してみて下さい。

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.AllowDrop = true;

    // TODO:デザイナーで以下のイベントを登録する
    button1.DragEnter += button1_DragEnter;
    button1.DragOver += button1_DragEnter;
    button1.DragDrop += button1_DragDrop;
}


// DragEnter, DragOverの実装
void button1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // 目的の操作(この場合はCopy)ができることと、
    // データの種類を確認する
    if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Copy) == DragDropEffects.Copy
        && e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        // Copyのエフェクトを表示する
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        // 対応していない場合
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
// DragDrop時の処理
void button1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // DragEnterと同様の判定を行う
    if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Copy) == DragDropEffects.Copy
        && e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
    {
        // 実際にデータを取り出す
        var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string [];

        // データが取得できたか判定する
        if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var filePath in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございます。
いつも助かります。

結論からひとつ確認したいのですが、ボタンにドラッグドロップは
『可能』なんですね？
DragDropもDragEnterも、フォームなどに実装はできていたので、
やり方自体は間違ってはいないとは自分では思っていますが、
AllowDropをTrueにしても、マウスカーソルが変化しないということは、
DragDrop及びDragEnterの処理にすら飛ばないということではないかと
思ったのですが、間違いなくできるということですよね？
私も、できるのか当たり前だとは思っているのですが…。

Comment: @たたぱた 可能なはずです。ですがファイルドロップの細部はOS/バージョンにより異なるので断言はできません。まずは上のコードを適当なフォームに貼ってConsole.WriteLineまで到達するか検証してみて下さい。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。返答が遅れてすみません。
いただいたコードをもとに、確認してみました。コードは確かに正常に動きました。
併せて、自分で組んだコードの部分も、しっかり動いていました。
決して言い訳ではないのですが、順番的には、1.動かない、2.いただいたコードを挿入後動作、3.いただいたコード部分を削除して元に戻しても動作…
等のようになっており、一体何か原因で動かなかったのかが解りません。
何はともあれ、無事に動くようになりました。ありがとうございました。